# Launch ClojureScript + ghost script from terminal

Tags: terminal, casperjs, clojurescript

I installed `phantomjs` and `casperjs`, created a new project with `lein new mies casper-ghost` and added the `[ghost "0.1.0-alpha1]` dependency to `project.clj`.

I then copied over the example code from https://github.com/casperjs/ghost to the `core.cljs` file and successfully compiled it, with `./scripts/build`.

When I try to run it with `casperjs out/casper_ghost.js` it gives me the error:

```
ClojureScript could not load :main, did you forget to specify :asset-path?
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: goog

  file:///usr/lib/node_modules/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js:1 in global code
```

I tried creating a custom build script as follows:

```
(require 'cljs.build.api)

(cljs.build.api/build "src"
                      {:main 'hello-world.core
                       :output-to "out/main.js"})
```

And ran that successfully with `lein -m clojure.main build.clj`, but running `out/main.js` with casperjs would cause the same error.

Can someone point me in the right direction how to run the ghost scripts from the linux terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Making the Google closure compiler write everything into a single file by using `:optimizations "simple"` to the build options did the trick.